# How do I fetch a model object by a nested value?

Tags: javascript, graphql

I'm new to GraphQL so I'm doing my first query and I'm trying to query for a nested key, `email`

Here is my schema

```
const UserLogin = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'UserLoginType',
  fields: () => ({
    login: { type: GraphQLString },
    email: { type: GraphQLString },
  }),
});

exports.UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'UserType',
  fields: () => ({
    id: NotNullStringType,
    name: { type: GraphQLString },
    state: { type: GraphQLString },
    login: { type: UserLogin },
  }),
});
```

And what I'm trying to do is build a query that takes an email and searches for the `UserType.login.email` value and return the first value that matches that email or null.

Thanks!

**Edit: In my `redux/actions.js` file I added:**

```
export const fetchLoginsByEmail = (userEmail) => {
  return createGraphqlAction(
    {
      query: `
        query fetchUserByEmail($userEmail: String!) {
          fetchUserByEmail(email: $userEmail) {
            login {
              email
            }
            state
            name
            id
          }
        }
      `,
      variables: {
        userEmail,
      }
    },
    FETCH_LOGINS_BY_EMAIL,
  );
};
```

And in my `query.js` file I have this in my `model.exports` object:

```
fetchUserByEmail: { 
    type: UserType,
    resolve: async (source, args, { user, loginId }) => {
      if (!user) {
        return null;
      }

      return serailize({
        ...user,
        login: await getLogin(loginId),
      });
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the arguments parameter for your query resolver.

Update your `query.js` into something like:

```
fetchUserByEmail: { 
    type: UserType,
    args: {
      email { type: GraphQLString }
    },
    resolve: async (source, args, { user, loginId }) => {
      // You can now use args.email here and filter your results with it
      console.log(args.email);

      if (!user) {
        return null;
      }

      return serailize({
        ...user,
        login: await getLogin(loginId),
      });
    },
  },
```